# Удаленная перезагрузка сервера

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Есть сервер, с материнкой ASUS p8z77-v и ununtu server.
Допустим ситуация, сервер завис, по x2go к нему не достучаться. Как его удаленно перезагрузить?
Есть варианты?

Comment: По ssh также нет возможности достучаться?

Comment: обычно, в нормальных датацентрах есть возможность подключиться специальным терминалом и увидеть консоль. Также, многие предоставляют способ ребутнуть сервер через специальную вебморду. Хеснер к примеру дает такую возможность.

Comment: Судя по материнке, сервер вполне домашний.

Comment: @Etki по ssh нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Если нужен только рестарт при зависании - поможет watchdog. Бывают в материнских платах встроенные (искать командой `dmesg | grep watchdog`) или внешние (например usb устройство с контактами для подключения reset);
2. Можно поставить IPMI плату и подлючаться к ней по отдельному сетевому каналу;
3. Можно поставить сетевой KVM, но управлять перезагрузкой/включением/выключением не получится (хотя может и такие модели бывают).

**Дополнено**: KVM есть и с поддержкой управления питанием, а вот IPMI плату для обычной настольной материнской платы еще поискать надо.

PS. Если бюджет крайне маленький, то можно сделать самоделку из роутера, прошив в него что-то типа OpenWRT. В подобных устройствах есть возможности управления светодиодами, вместо них можно припаять транзистор и управлять reset'ом "сервера" или даже питанием, но естественно это потребует времени и, возможно, получения некоторых дополнительных знаний.

Comment: Плюсую, только это не оффтопик. Ну, сами посудите, а где еще, как не у коллег, с котрыми он здесь общается (задавая вопросы и сам давая ответы) программисту получить практические рекомендации.

Comment: Убедили. Убрал пункт про оффтопик

Comment: @tutankhamun, вопросы по настройке серверов вполне онтопик.

Comment: Перечитал справку. Виноват. Исправлюсь.

Comment: а какой из вариантов позволит удаленно зайти в bios? например чтобы была возможность переустановить ту же ОС

Comment: Однозначно KVM. IPMI нужно смотреть на каком этапе позволяет подключиться. Кроме того IPMI позволяет подключать образы носителей через сеть (по крайней мере настоящие серверные модели), но IPMI-карту не так просто купить и нужно проверять на совместимость в материнской платой